# string-insert-rectangle equivalent in Xemacs

Tags: emacs, xemacs

On Emacs I can use string-insert-rectangle to overwrite the text of a rectangle selection. I was wondering if there is anything similar to this in Xemacs (using Xemacs 21.4.22). I currently have to do this in two steps. 
1) Delete the text I want to replace
2) Prefix the text I want to add.
I would like to make this a single step issue just like in Emacs. 
Thanks for any hint.
G

Comment: It sounds like you want string-rectangle, with pending-delete-mode enabled.